# How to host flower on a remote machine that can also be accessed over the internet

Tags: python, celery, flower

I am trying to run `flower` on a remote ubuntu server. However, I am unsure on what address/port to run it on so that other people can login (I have the basic auth set up) and check their `celery` workers. The ubuntu server is actually an EC2 instance, so am I supposed to use its private or public ip address? Do I just open any standard port? In their docs, they use their example setup with http://localhost/5555 but I do not think that will work if `flower` will be running on a remote server. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flower runs on 5555 by default- which port are you running it on?  The private IP is only available if the requests are coming from INSIDE your amazon network, so probably public.

So, if my guesses are right, you want to create an AWS security rule allowing traffic from "anywhere" to port 5555 and apply that to your instance, and then access that instance using its public ip like
http://50.31.10.99:5555

Comment: thanks a lot. I don't think it matters which port flower is running on so long as I know I will need to open it to the public. So far I only got this setup on my local laptop so I was confused as how I would be deploying flower remotely. Your answer really helped me to understand this